# Angular test: override to use template instead of templateUrl

Tags: angular, testing, mocking, testbed

I have a component which contains `iframe`. To prevent loading not existing URL from iframe in tests I would like to mock component's template. I thought I could do it using `TestBed.overrideComponent()` but it has no effect. When test runs I can see the original template is present and iframe loads non-existing url.

What I tried:

```
fixture = TestBed.overrideComponent(IFrameComponent, {
  remove: {
    templateUrl: './iframe.component.html'
  },
  add: {
    template: '<div></div>'
  }
}).createComponent(IFrameComponent);
```

How can I override component to use `template` instead of `templateUrl`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why it didnt work for me was that I called `TestBed.overrideComponent()` *after* `compileComponents()`.

Proper order is this:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   declarations: [IFrameComponent]
}).overrideComponent(IFrameComponent, {
   remove: {
      templateUrl: './iframe.component.html'
   },
   add: {
      template: '<div data-test-iframe="iframe"></div>'
   }
}).compileComponents();
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(IFrameComponent);
```